# Assign an ID in one column based on the ID in another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have first assigned a unique id based on column 1

```
column1   id.1 column2 
   A      1      C
   A      1      B
   B      2      B
   C      3      A
   C      3      D
```

and I would like to allocate the id.1 values to column2

```
column1   id.1 column2  id.2
   A      1      C        3
   A      1      B        2
   B      2      B        2
   C      3      A        1
   C      3      D        NA
```

I am sorry if this has been answered again. I am trying for long to find a beautiful solution on that. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `factor` as shown below:

```
 transform(df, id.2 = factor(column2, unique(column1), unique(id.1)))
  column1 id.1 column2 id.2
1       A    1       C    3
2       A    1       B    2
3       B    2       B    2
4       C    3       A    1
5       C    3       D <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu for the help. I highly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

`match` is the usual way to do this:

```
df$id.2 = df$id.1[match(df$column2, df$column1)]
df
#   column1 id.1 column2 id.2
# 1       A    1       C    3
# 2       A    1       B    2
# 3       B    2       B    2
# 4       C    3       A    1
# 5       C    3       D   NA
```

Or using `dplyr` syntax:

```
mutate(df, id.2 = id.1[match(column2, column1)])
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'column1   id.1 column2 
    A      1      C
    A      1      B
    B      2      B
    C      3      A
    C      3      D', header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gregor for the neat and quick answer